# java Stream collect to TreeMap in reverse order

Tags: java, maps, java-stream, treemap

I have the following code to collect a map from the stream, and convert it to a treemap

```
Map<String, String> result = myMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getScore, Person::getName));
    return new TreeMap<>(result);
```

Is there a way I could return a descending sorted treeMap in the same line? I cannot pass the comparator as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the four argument [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method that returns a collector. Assuming the `getScore` method returns an `Integer`(or you can stay with `String` if you want but it will be less usable I think) :

```
//supplier of TreeMap with your custom comparator
Supplier<TreeMap<Integer, String>> myMapSupplier = () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());

Map<Integer, String> result = myMap.values()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getScore, Person::getName, (s, s2) -> s, myMapSupplier));
```

The last element is the supplier of the `Map`. As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) states :

> mapSupplier - a function which returns a new, empty `Map` **into which the results will be inserted**

So you can still have a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` in a single call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted` with `Comparator` and use `LinkedHashMap` to collect as below,

```
Map<String, String> result = myMap.values().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getScore, Person::getName, (x, y) -> x,LinkedHashMap::new));
```

I would suggest using `int` for score as String would be lexically compared. So your result map would be `Map<Integer, String>`.

I hope it helps.